# Android: OnClickListener for PreferenceCategory

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-preferences

Is it possible to have an `OnClickListener` for a `PreferenceCategory` in a `PreferenceFragment`?

I have tried things like this:

**XML**

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Nothing to see here folks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:key="prefCatKey">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:key="randomKey"
            android:title="Don't do anything" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

**Java**

```
PreferenceCategory prefCat = (PreferenceCategory)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("RTXOffsetCategory");
prefCat.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
    {
        Log.d("Tag", "Do stuff here");
        return false;
    }
});
```

The variable `prefCat` comes back with a correct value, but the `OnPreferenceClickListener()` is never called.

Is it even possible to make a `PreferenceCategory` call a listener?

If it is possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `PreferenceCategory` has been deprecated in API level 29. Instead, AndroidX [Preference Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary) is recommended.

You can maybe use [Preference.onPreferenceClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener) to implement the same behavior.

Comment: I know that `PreferenceCategory` is deprecated, unfortunately I don't get to pick the API level. If you look at the code I posted, I did use `Preference.onPreferenceClickListener`.

Comment: I have never used `PreferenceCategory` or any similar associated library, so I'd not be of much help past this point.